# Angular js-User automatically likes a program

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I am new to angular js..
I have implemented a website with Ruby on rails and angular in which a user can like a program..But in a peculiar scenario whenever a user clicks on a program,the program page will automatically show that the user likes the program,whether he has clicked on the like button or not. and his facebook profile pic is shown

The following is the Javascript code:-

```
 woi.controller("FriendsController", ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$routeParams', '$filter', 'userAPI', function($scope, $rootScope, $routeParams, $filter, userAPI){
        $scope.recommended = [];
        $scope.paginate    = [];        
        $scope.friends     = [];

        $scope.amount   = 0;
        $scope.step     = 5;
        $scope.showMore = true;

        if($rootScope.device.isTablet){
            $scope.step = 30;
        }
        if($rootScope.device.isMobile){
            $scope.step = 20;
        }

        $scope.loadMore = function(){
            if(!$scope.friends.length)
                return false;
            $scope.amount= $scope.amount + $scope.step;

            if($scope.amount >= $scope.friends.length){
                $scope.showMore = false;
                $scope.amount   = $scope.friends.length;
            }

            $scope.paginate = $scope.friends.slice(0, $scope.amount);
        };

      userAPI.friends({programmeid:$rootScope.Programmeid}, function(rs){

            if(!rs.getpeoplielikeprogram)
                return false;

            $scope.friends = addData(rs.getpeoplielikeprogram.peoplielikeprogram);

            $scope.loadMore();
        });
    }]);
```

My Html is as Follows:-

```
<div class="available-in" ng-show="showAvailableIn" ng-controller="AvailableInController">
  <h6 class="subtitle">AVAILABLE IN</h6>

  <ul class="list-available">
    <li ng-repeat="channel in availableIn">
      <a href="{{channel.storeurl}}"><img ng-src="{{channel.logofileurl}}" alt="{{channel.storeinformation}}" /></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<!-- / availableIn -->

<div class="friends" ng-show="friends.length>0" ng-controller="FriendsController">
  <h6 class="subtitle">FRIENDS</h6>

  <ul class="list-friends">
    <p class="title_pink">{{friends[0].username}}<span class="text_woi"><span ng-show="friends.length - 1 > 0"> and {{friends.length-1}} others</span> liked it</span></p>
    <li class="item animate bounceInDown clearfix friend_inline_list" ng-repeat="r in paginate" >
      <div class="thumb" css-bg-image="../assets/img/cast-default.png">
        <div css-bg-image="{{r.userimage | filterDefaultImage}}" title="{{r.username}}">&nbsp;</div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <p class="loadmore" ng-show="showMore">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" title="Load more Recommended" ng-click="loadMore()">More..</a>
  </p>
</div>
<!-- / friends -->

<!-- Share with friends -->
<!-- <div class="friends" ng-controller="FbShareController" style="margin-top:30px;" ng-show="userLogged=='on'" > -->
<div class="friends" style="margin-top:30px;" ng-show="userLogged=='on'" >

  <ul class="list-friends list_share_friends">
    <li class="logo" ng-click="shareLinkOnFb()"></li>
    <li class="logo_text" ng-click="shareLinkOnFb()">Share with Friends</li>
    <li class="clearfix"></li>
  </ul>

</div>

<div class="feed fb" ng-show="showFacebook==true && paginateFb.length > 0">
  <ul>
    <li class="colorfull">
      <h6 class="subtitle">FB newsfeed</h6>
      <a ng-click="loadMoreFb()">{{fbText}}</a>
    </li>

    <li class="item clearfix" ng-repeat="post in paginateFb">
      <div class="thumb">
        <div class="wrapper">
          <img ng-src="{{facebookProfilePic}}">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="info">
        <span class="account-name">{{post.from.name}}</span>

        <!-- <div class="post">
          {{post.message}}
          <br/>
          <img ng-src="{{post.picture}}">
        </div>  -->
        <div class="post" ng-bind-html>
          <span ng-bind-html-unsafe="post.message | replaceLinks"></span><br/>
          <img ng-src="{{post.picture}}">
        </div>
        <br/>
        <span class="time">{{post.updated_time|facebookTime}}</span>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>
<!-- / feed facebook -->

<div class="feed twitter" ng-show="showTwitter==true && paginateTwitter.length > 0">
  <ul>
    <li class="colorfull">
      <h6 class="subtitle">Twitter</h6>
      <a ng-click="loadMoreTweets()">{{twitterText}}</a>
    </li>

    <li class="item clearfix" ng-repeat="post in paginateTwitter">
      <div class="thumb">
        <div class="wrapper">
          <img ng-src="{{post.user.profile_image_url}}">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="info">
        <span class="account-name">{{post.user.name}} </span>
        <div class="post" ng-bind-html>
          <span ng-bind-html-unsafe="post.text | replaceLinks"></span>
        </div>
        <span class="time">{{post.created_at|twitterTime}}</span>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</aside>
```

Please help me with this

Comment: Can you please post the HTML template?

Comment: @DavinTryon Please check the question..I have updated it

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your problem is in the *FriendsController*, it's just responsible for populating that scope with information from the *userAPI*. I noticed that there's some more logic in this template from another controller - not sure which:

```
<li class="logo" ng-click="shareLinkOnFb()"></li>
```

Take a look at whichever controller has the scope function *shareLinkOnFb* and see what it is doing.

Comment: will check and let you know..Thanks for the help